# React Server Components Performance on SEO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-server-components

So this is a fairly new topic, React Server Components has recently been released, comparing to SSR/Next.js, how does it affect SEO?

Since the component is rendered in the server dynamically when it is requested, it is not really as static as SSR like Next.js, will search engine fail to index those component if I use it?

A demo can found [here](https://github.com/reactjs/server-components-demo)

We can see that in `api.server.js`,

```
async function renderReactTree(res, props) {
  await waitForWebpack();
  const manifest = readFileSync(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/react-client-manifest.json'),
    'utf8'
  );
  const moduleMap = JSON.parse(manifest);
  pipeToNodeWritable(React.createElement(ReactApp, props), res, moduleMap);
}

function sendResponse(req, res, redirectToId) {
  const location = JSON.parse(req.query.location);
  if (redirectToId) {
    location.selectedId = redirectToId;
  }
  res.set('X-Location', JSON.stringify(location));
  renderReactTree(res, {
    selectedId: location.selectedId,
    isEditing: location.isEditing,
    searchText: location.searchText,
  });
}
```

I understand this can help to reduce the workload for client's device, since the component are rendered on the server and sent to the client, and that the component can be rendered with the secret stored in server as we can just pass it in as props rather we sending the secret to client.

But if SEO matters, is SSR preferred over React Server Component?

Comment: The only nuance here is that it won’t be “either or” for server components and SSR. The react team has been pretty emphatic that you’ll be able to use them together, so you can use SSR to look like a fully server-rendered app on first page load and then your app will be a regular react app (with both client and server components)

Answer (score 7):

Server Components are **complementary** to rendering into HTML, not an alternative. **The plan is to have both.**

Server Components were not *released*. What was released is an early tech preview in the spirit of sharing our research. This preview doesn’t include an HTML renderer. The `api.server.js` file from the demo you mentioned contains a comment about this:

```
    const html = readFileSync(
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/index.html'),
      'utf8'
    );
    // Note: this is sending an empty HTML shell, like a client-side-only app.
    // However, the intended solution (which isn't built out yet) is to read
    // from the Server endpoint and turn its response into an HTML stream.
    res.send(html);
```

By the time Server Components are officially released, there will be a streaming HTML renderer for the first render.

It’s not built yet.

Comment: Once you have the HTML renderer can the content be visible in page source?

Comment: Hey, is this streaming HTML renderer still planned? I don’t think it’s in Next.js’s implementation, it sends a bunch of JS commands on first load, not HTML.

Answer (score 2):

It should be same from SEO point of view as SPA.

What happens with classic React SPA is, it loads React components (which are essentially JS functions) as part of the JS bundle, and then it starts to request data from the backend in JSON format. After JSON is fetched, it is rendered via the React component functions and inserted into the DOM. Modern crawlers use V8 engine (or maybe smth else if it's Bing :D), they wait until page is fully loaded and all JSON data is loaded and all components are actually rendered - and then it crawls the resulting DOM.

GoogleBot is crawling SPAs that way for at least 3 years now, probably more - so if you were thinking that SSR is essential for SEO, no, it is not. There were plenty of investigations into this, random example: https://medium.com/@l.mugnaini/spa-and-seo-is-googlebot-able-to-render-a-single-page-application-1f74e706ab11

So essentially for crawler it doesn't really matter, how exactly React component is rendered. In case of React Server Components, component function resides on server and is never transferred to the client as part of the JS bundle. So instead of requesting JSON data, the application requests rendered component in some intermediate format (not HTML btw). Result of that is transferred to the client and is getting rendered to the DOM. So the end result is still the same - it's some DOM elements that the bot can crawl.

Comment: Although Server Components render into a richer format, it is very much a part of the plan to have an HTML streaming renderer that consumes that format and emits HTML.

Comment: Makes sense from perf point of view, yep. But again, does it really matter in the context of the SEO and crawling, which format exactly is used over the wire, HTML string or smth else? I think it doesn't. GoogleBot will crawl it anyway (after it's inserted into the DOM) :)

Comment: As far as I know, rendering to HTML is still better for crawling because it gets indexed faster.